# Stack Overflow site loading slowly

Tags: support

This site some time loading very slow for when i type `http://stackoverflow.com/` in my browser and when put some answers in any question! I saw the problems in frequently of few days .

What problem ?

And see this below image .This image was footer of this site(SO)

[image]

.Must see this Rev Date

rev 2013.5.22.1028 . 
My question is  any connectivity for this site loading slowly and the rev date is updated for site management ???

**Edit**:

I am Tested the page speed in Google page speed

I have tested in 6 time . 4 time its good for 94% speed . But 2 time its loading 89% and 83%.

Now 92 %

Click quick, quick this link

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fstackoverflow.com_2F&mobile=true

**Question Update :**

I know the 92% is a good speed . But My another question is why the page speed  was not a static page speed.Its some time increase some time decrease on the google page speed !!!!

Comment: The site is loading fine for me (am on mobile broadband)

Comment: Not , But FaceBook and any other websites are loading very quick .but stack overflow web site some time load slowly!!

Comment: I don't Know, Why is slow loading !!! But it's a good website . Does  any network problem to me ????\

Comment: Please click this link . this page speed was changed

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fstackoverflow.com_2F&mobile=true

Comment: okay ! but this site page speed was not a static.its some time increase some time decrease on the google page speed !!!!

Answer (score 4):

It's all about traffic. There is no direct connection between the server hosting Stack Overflow and your machine.

Instead, there are routers and gateways and the data packets are doing "hops" from one to another until they reach their destination. [More about hops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_%28networking%29).

Sometimes one or more of those routers/gateways might be jammed and cause slowness. Keep in mind that for each site there are different waypoints (assuming of course they have different hosts) that's why Facebook might be fast while Stack Overflow is slow and vice versa.

To see those hops, run `cmd` then type `tracert stackoverflow.com`. Here is my output as an example:

```
Tracing route to stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.16] over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  my.firewall [10.1.1.254]
  2    20 ms    20 ms    20 ms  ASR-PT.02-lo0.bb.012.net.il [212.199.17.109]
  3    20 ms    20 ms    21 ms  CORE-PT-MX-xe-7-0-1-2222.ip4.012.net.il [212.199.242.150]
  4     *       22 ms    22 ms  BRDR-PT-ae0-2091.ip4.012.net.il [212.199.73.105]
  5    86 ms    86 ms    87 ms  EDGE-LON-MX-01-so-2-0-0-0.ip4.012.net.il [80.179.165.154]
  6    92 ms    91 ms    91 ms  77.67.61.65
  7   160 ms   158 ms   159 ms  xe-10-1-0.nyc32.ip4.tinet.net [89.149.181.193]
  8   161 ms   160 ms   161 ms  internap-gw.ip4.tinet.net [216.221.159.206]
  9   163 ms   163 ms   162 ms  border1.po1-20g-bbnet1.nym008.pnap.net [216.52.95.1]
 10   162 ms   162 ms   161 ms  stackexchange-1.border1.nym008.pnap.net [74.201.252.22]
 11   177 ms   159 ms   158 ms  stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.16]

Trace complete.
```

As you see, four local waypoints and four in New York.